# XIB Constraints... keep getting Misplaced Views

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I am just not grasping the auto layout constraints in XCODE XIB's... I am not sure what I am missing, can anyone please help?

So I create a new Cocoa Touch Class... view controller and have it also create the XIB... I lay out the XIB the way I want it to look... with the base values to wANY hANY... I then use add missing constraints to create all the constraints so they are relative to what I dragged and dropped.

I run the code and the view I created just appears all wobbly.

I check and I see that I have "Misplaced View" warnings... so I try various things... update constraints.. does nothing that I can tell.. I click on the items in my view and I see the frames (orange dashed lines) are all huge compared to the actual item...  I try the update frames...  This gets fired of the misplaced views error, the then the layout in the XIB editor just resizes all my things to the weird frames that somehow got defined.... and at runtime the view still doesn't even show up right as well...

What am I missing here, this should be so complicated... All the constraints are laid out relative to one another, but no matter what I do at run time it is goofy no matter what I try....

I am just not understanding something here... I would appreciate any help... this is getting beyond frustrating... all the auto fix stuff doesn't seem to do jack  at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I think I it has finally clicked.   Not sure how to delete the original question